# Combine MapReduce result with data

Tags: join, hadoop, mapreduce

How could i combine with map/reduce these two files:

**File1. Data.**

```
1   name:foo1,position:bar1
2   name:foo2,position:bar2
3   name:foo3,position:bar3
4   name:foo4,position:bar4
5   name:foo5,position:bar5
```

**File2. MR computed result.**

```
1   1,2
3   3,4,5
```

**The goal is:**

```
1   foo1,foo2
3   foo3,foo4,foo5
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a join, which is definitely doable but a bit of a pain in straight map reduce. Have you taken a look at higher level languages like Pig or Hive to simplify this task?